# PHP and adding same value to several array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP. I would like to add same value to several array keys.

This works:

```
$array = array();

$value = 1000;

$from = 1;
$to = 5;

for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++)
{
  $array[$i] = $value;
}

$value = 2000;

$from = 10;
$to = 14;

for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++)
{
  $array[$i] = $value;
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($array);
print "</pre>";
```

Anyway, I'm looking for a shorter way. So, I have tried this:

```
$array = array();
$array[range(1, 5)] = 1000;
$array[range(10, 14)] = 2000;

print "<pre>";
print_r($array);
print "</pre>";
```

This did not work at all.

Any ideas how the job could be done with less code?

Comment: why can't you use `for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) $array[$i] = 1000;`?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Thanks, but anyway, I'm looking for something else.

Comment: @IlyaBursov I saw your reply, but now it has been deleted. There was something interesting, but I do not remember the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the obvious and most readable variant is:

```
$array = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=5;$i++) $array[$i] = 1000;
for ($i=10; $i<=14;$i++) $array[$i] = 2000;
```

another option is:

```
$array = array();
$array = array_fill_keys(range(1,5), 1000) + $array;
$array = array_fill_keys(range(10,14), 2000) + $array;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array_fill(1, 5, 1000);
$b = array_fill(10, 5, 2000);
$array = $a + $b;
```

If you want `$from` and `$to` variables you can use the following code:

```
$a = array_fill($from_1, $to_1 - $from_1 + 1, 1000);
$b = array_fill($from_2, $to_2 - $from_2 + 1, 2000);
$array = $a + $b;
```

Comment: This is the most concise and readable method IMO.  This is the exact reason that PHP offers this function -- so use it.  For-loops may work faster in terms of nanoseconds on these small arrays, but `array_fill()` speaks literally about the process being performed.  This is the way I would do it if it was my project. +1

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
array_fill_keys(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 10000);
array_fill_keys(array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), 20000);
```

Other way would be

```
array_fill_keys(array_values(range(1,5)), 10000);
array_fill_keys(array_values(range(10,14)), 20000);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a better way than by using a for loop (there are some shorter solutions, but they are much less readable and/or perform much worse). If you are doing this a lot why not turn it into a function:

```
function array_set(&$array, $start, $end, $value) {
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        $array[$i] = $value;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
$test = array();

array_set($test, 3, 5, 1000);

var_dump($test);
```

Which produces: `array(3) { [3]=> int(1000) [4]=> int(1000) [5]=> int(1000) }`

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) takes a function to apply to every element in an array. That function can simple return the desired value.

```
array_map(function () use ($value){return $value;}, array_flip(range(1,5)));
```

A complete (ugly, unreadable, not recommended) one-line solution could be:

```
print_r(array_filter(array_map(function ($v){return $v < 5 ? 10000 : ($v > 8 ? 20000 : false);}, array_flip(range(1,14)))));
```